# Video Player to play video

Tags: c#, xaml, windows-8, youtube

I want to play youtube video in windows 8 application with `XAML` and c#.

I don't want to play youtube video from WebView control of windows 8 i want to play video from my own control is that possible ? can anyone help me for this please ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try [MyToolkit](http://mytoolkit.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=YouTube&referringTitle=Documentation) on CodePlex. You can use GetVideoUriAsync to get a URI to feed to a MediaElement.

```
var url = await YouTube.GetVideoUriAsync(youTubeId, YouTubeQuality.Quality1080P);
var player = new MediaElement();
player.Source = url.Uri;
```

Comment: This package doesn't work anymore.

Answer (score 0):

Yes this is possible you can take a look on these three links:

[YouTube API](https://developers.google.com/youtube/)

[Manage YouTube Over Code](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/143669/Manage-YouTube-using-C-and-Youtube-API-1-6)

[Example how to Play Videos with YouTube API](https://developers.google.com/youtube/2.0/developers_guide_dotnet)

Comment: Hello but i want to play video in Windows 8 XAML is there any player to play video for windows 8 XAML ?

Comment: Sory but what is "Windows 8 XAML"? XAML is XAML. You can use any player for example the VLC, if you get a Video over the YouTube API:
Uri  videoEntryUrl = 
  new Uri("http://gdata.youtube.com/feeds/api/videos/ADos_xW4_J0"); 
Video video = request.Retrieve<Video>(videoEntryUrl);
printVideoEntry(videoEntry);

you can play it in any player. Just read the Dokumenation carfully its not that hard and can be done in 30 min.

Answer (score 0):

First thing its YouTube TOS violation.

But if you really want to do that, first you need to extract the streaming URL from the response from YouTube when you do a request.Check this code and port it to c#

[youtube-dl](http://rg3.github.com/youtube-dl/)